# Game maker collisions only work sometimes

Tags: collision, game-maker

This is my code for the enemies in my game

```
//Collision
if (place_meeting(x,y,Object_Wall))
{
    speed = 0
    direction = point_direction(x,y,Object_Wall.x,Object_Wall.y) + random_range(160,200)
    speed = sp / 2
    time = random_range(room_speed * 0.75,room_speed * 3)
}
```

When the zombie hits a wall, it should turn back and walk the other way.
This works most of the time but sometimes they will just drift through walls and if they are following the player and he goes next to a wall they go through it.
I don't know why it doesn't work sometimes and would like help to fix this.

I am using `Object_Wall`as a parent object and they work with it but the problem occurs with it's children.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `point_direction(x,y,Object_Wall.x,Object_Wall.y)`, it's not object which was found using `place_meeting(x,y,Object_Wall)`.

`place_meeting(x,y,Object_Wall)` will check collsion with all instances of object `Object_Wall`. But when you use in `point_direction` object id instead instance id, GM will take first (in creation order) instance of object `Object_Wall`.

You can take instance id using, for example, `collision_circle` function.
But I recommend use `Collision` event and `other` keyword inside it.

Comment: So when it collides, I can use with(other) to get the co-ordinates of the wall, then use these to walk away from?

Comment: If wall object in not marked as `Solid`, you can do, for example, `x=xprevious; y=yprevious;` and then change direction `direction = point_direction(x, y, other.x, other.y) + random_range(160,200);`